# Python3, connected strings not working

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out why my code doesn't work when I'm trying to print a collection of strings. In Python 2 I could usually do:

```
print ('test is') + ('this')
```

However, in Python 3 it prodcues the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I have tried replacing '+' with 'and' which works but the string doesn't come out after that. Can someone please explain to me how and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3 `print` is not a statement unlike Python 2. It is a function. Moreover that function returns a `NoneType`.

So when you type `print ('test is') + ('this')` in Python 3.x, you are trying to add `NoneType` to `str` and hence the error.

The correct thing ( I expect you want to do this) is to type :

`print('test is' + 'this')`

Comment: wouldn't that add a space to each part of the two strings?

Comment: No.  `+` simply concatenates and does not add any spaces of its own.

Comment: Using `,` does.

Comment: yes. I meant, in this case it doesnt since there is no `,`

Comment: or print('test is', 'this', sep="")

Comment: If you just want to concatenate then try `print('test'+'code')` if you want spaces between then do `print('test '+'code')` for spaces this is not the only code you can write it in many ways just try it out

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print two string in Python 3 then you need to contain them all in one bracket, `print (('test is ')+('this'))`, so that it's printed all as one string instead of adding `print('test is ')`(nonetype) to `('this')`(string).